Fastlane build failing with error: Build input file cannot be found
The error messages have the following form:

error: Build input file cannot be found: '{path}'. Did you forget to
declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule
which produces it? (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')

These errors happen when using Fastlane build_app but they do not happen if I pull out the xcodebuild command and run it independently.

xcodebuild -workspace wind_chime_mobile.xcworkspace -scheme
wind_chime_mobile -configuration Release -destination
'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath
/Users/bobdevereux/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2024-07-18/wind_chime_mobile
2024-07-18\ 11.05.11.xcarchive clean archive

